# How to use VBA to click a image link on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I'm trying to pull documents from an internal website for multiple accounts at a time.

I'm using VBA in Excel 2010. I created the code to login and navigate until I get to the part where I need to click an image button.

Below is the related source code. First there is a function:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    <!--
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
                var theform;
                if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
                       theform = document.Form1;
                }
                else {
                       theform = document.forms["Form1"];
                }
                theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
                theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                theform.submit();
        }
    // -->
    </script>
```

And then skipping down there is this block of code where "Print.gif" is the button to click:

```
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="/crystalreportviewers10/css/default.css">
<table id="CrystalReportViewer1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
   style="height:1043px;width:901px;Z-INDEX: 101;LEFT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 8px">
    <tr><td>
    <div style="width: 901px; height: 1043px;position:relative">
    <div style="height:30px;width:901px;top:0px;left:0px;">
    <table class="crtoolbar" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr nowrap>
    <td nowrap width=16>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap width=24px>
    <input type="image" name="CrystalReportViewer1:_ctl2:_ctl0" 
       title="Show/Hide Group Tree"
     onmouseover="this.src='/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/grouptree_over.gif'"
     onmouseout="this.src='/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/grouptree.gif'"
     src="/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/grouptree.gif" alt="" border="0"
      style="height:24px;width:24px;" /></td>
    <td nowrap width=16>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap width=24px>
    <img title="Print"
        onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('CrystalReportViewer1:_ctl2:_ctl3','')"
        onmouseover="this.src='/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/print_over.gif'"
        onmouseout="this.src='/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/print.gif'"
        src="/crystalreportviewers10/images/toolbar/print.gif" alt="" border="0"
        style="height:24px;width:24px;" /></td>
```

I've tried a few different ways to fire the "onclick" but I'm having trouble because it looks like it passes to the above function to navigate to the correct page. So far I've tried:

```vb
        For Each obj In IE.Document.all
    '        MsgBox obj.innerHTML
            If InStr(obj.innerHTML, "Print") > 0 Then
            obj.Click
    '            Exit For
        End If
        Next
```

or

```vb
        For Each obj In IE.Document.all
            If obj.Name = "Print" Then
            obj.Click
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

and a couple variations that have failed me so far. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let us know the results.

```
For Each obj In ie.document.all
      If InStr(obj.innerHTML, "Print") > 0 Then
         obj.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:__doPostBack('CrystalReportViewer1:_ctl2:_ctl3','')"
      End If
Next
```

OR

```
For Each obj In ie.document.all
    If InStr(obj.innerHTML, "Print") > 0 Then
        obj.Click
        obj.FireEvent ("onclick")
    End If
Next
```